# React JS: Create a function that reads props and passes into render

Tags: reactjs

I might have butchered the title/question completely as I'm new to React...

I have multiple objects which I'd like to pass into a component that'll output items in a certain format. The issue is that I'm not certain on how to pass in props into the object or component.

```
const ObjectA = {
   name: "objectA",
   data: {
     values: "Adds",
     dateRange: [props.state.startDate, props.state.endDate]
   }
}
```

```
const DisplayObject = ({data}) => {
   <div>
      <RenderChart {data=data}/>
   </div>
}
```

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: moment("2019-12-01", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
      endDate: moment("2019-12-31", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
      focusedInput: null,
    };
  };
  render() {
    return (
       <DisplayObject {data=ObjectA.data} />
       <DisplayObject {data=ObjectB.data} />
    );
  };
}
```

Currently I have it such that I have the entire code from DisplayObject and ObjectA, etc under render() but this is getting messy and also repetitive with DisplayObject being used multiple times. And in these I'm passing in this.state.startDate, this.state.endDate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you want to pass it like

```
<DisplayObject data={ObjectA.data} />
```

you don't need to encompass the jsx attribute in curly brackets

Comment: Thanks Matt - as a follow-up question, how do I make it such that ObjectA has access to props set in class Page?

Comment: hmm im not sure what the use case is but you could try changing ObjectA to a let instead of const and redeclare Object A above return in the render method?? This is not best practice but I'd have to know more about why you're doing that to think of the best way...

Comment: Hi Matt - the issue is if I run the code above, it's giving me an error stating that props is not defined.

Comment: did you also fix  <RenderChart data={data}/> ?